# directives - initialize ngModel from Controller

Tags: angularjs

Why ngModel doesnt set the initial value from the Controller?

Example: http://plnkr.co/edit/sGFv4zpVtvpsmUx1c9F3

```
    angular.module('customControl', [])
  .directive('contenteditable', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'A', // only activate on element attribute
      require: '?ngModel', // get a hold of NgModelController
      link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
        if(!ngModel) return; // do nothing if no ng-model

        // Specify how UI should be updated
        ngModel.$render = function() {
          element.html(ngModel.$viewValue || '');
        };
      }
    };
  });

  function TestCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.userContent = 'It Works!!!!';
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You gave the module the name "customController", so you have to give the ng-app a name as well.

Change `<html ng-app>`

to

`<html ng-app="customControl">`

and it should fix your problems.

Working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/bVYavNKuwV9BjrDNz2Hm

Comment: Sorry, I was not referring to the textarea, but to the "contenteditable" directive, I've updated the example http://plnkr.co/edit/sGFv4zpVtvpsmUx1c9F3

Comment: I've updated my answer, but I'm having a further look at your directive now. I'm not sure it's actually changing the value of the scope variable userContent - that is what you want, right?

Comment: Yes, I want to initialize the value from the controller. I dont understand because looking into the angular's "input" directive there's nothing diferent from that, you can even comment out everything and keep only `ctrl.$render = function() {
    element.val(isEmpty(ctrl.$viewValue) ? '' : ctrl.$viewValue);
  };` and it still works

Comment: I need ngModel for validation.

Comment: Ah, it was a simple problem after all. After looking at everything else it came down to not specifying the app name in the HTML.